# Changing the background color of a div by referencing an external CSS file and property using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to reference a CSS file and take property from that file and using in a div element.

```
var divVar = document.getElementById("change");
var externalCSSSource = document.getComputedStyle("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.4.4/ace/theme/monokai");
var externalCSSProperty = externalCSSSource.getPropertyValue('.ace-monokai');

divVar.style.backgroundColor = externalCSSProperty;
```

This code doesn't work. I might not be referencing the property correctly.

Comment: [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) takes an element not a stylesheet URL.

Comment: because getPropertyValue returns a DOMString containing the value of a specified CSS property and not only background color !

Comment: @Alex How do you get the value of a specified CSS property?